# No easy missions left on Borderlands?

Tags: borderlands

I've played a few missions now and reached Level 13. However, I've only got 4 missions available at the moment, all of them are rated at Level 15 (Tough) or Level 14 (Hard).

Are there other, easier missions I can take on first or something?

Comment: The given levels are just recommendations and it should be easy to make quests 3-4 lvls above

Answer (score 3):

As you've not stated where you are in the game, nor what you've done so far I can only give general advice:

Your best bet is to try some of the level 14 missions, taking it slowly so you can gain XP as you go. Either that or just go exploring, you'll likely find some more missions else where.

Answer (score 2):

As a general advice, if you want to grind a bit, check the map for question marks, so you might find new areas that can give you more missions. In some areas there are NPCs with missions, etc.

Answer (score -1):

Your best bet would be the following two DLC packs: Claptrap's New Robot Revolution & The Zombie Island of Dr. Ned.

Claptrap's New Robot Revolution DLC involves fighting against the Interplanetary Ninja Assassin Claptrap, a specialized version of the normally kind-hearted robot that is designed by Hyperion to kill the Vault Hunters. However, he becomes self-aware of how poorly his fellow Claptraps are being treated and forms a 'robot revolution' or as he calls it, a robolution, consisting of an army of very angry Claptraps.

As for The Zombie Island of Dr. Ned DLC, the story consists of you aiding the Jakobs Corporation in stopping a massive zombie outbreak. Since you are only level 13, the game keeps these enemies at the same level as you, and after a while you will find yourself leveled up pretty well.

Personally, I leveled up from level 10 to 20 just by doing Zombie Island, and beating Claptrap's DLC gives you access to a room filled with weapon caches. My only advice: try to go into Zombie Island with either Incendiary or Explosive weapons (SMGs and Combat Rifles work the best) and have Corrosive weapons (preferably a shotgun or SMG) for Claptrap, as Corrosive weaponry works the best on enemies with armor or metal based skin, which is what 90% of that areas fighters are going to be.